# Speed of light through experiment

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, observers

If nothing can travel faster than light.

A thought experiment:

Imagine two men having a tug of war the length of the "rope" between them is a little longer than the distance that  light can travel in 1 second.

If one man let's go of the rope briefly say for 0.5 of a second and then re grips.

Does the other man notice(stumble back) in sync with the man letting go...  Or is there a delay?

Firstly I don't want to get into the points regarding the rope re it would break under its own weight or it's not possible to make a rope that long.. it's purely do do with if such a rope existed and the flow of information not practical considerations or material science..

Comment: No worries about the possibility of such a rope. Just reduce your brief time from 1 second to 1 nanosecond and you can use a 30 centimeter rope!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a delay (as measured by the clocks of the men). The speed of sound in the rope is after all less than the speed of light.

Relativity shows that "simultaneous" is not well defined for different moving frames of reference (e.g. an observer moving past the scene on a spaceship), but the men are at rest relatively to each other and has no problem with the timekeeping when they compare notes afterwards.

There is a common "paradox" where people postulate a perfectly rigid rod or inextensible rope and ask what happens when you push or pull on it. Relativity answers that there are no perfectly rigid bodies.

Answer (score 2):

See this 40 second video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5s1cMNTmGs

The bottom of the slinky doesn't even know the top of the slinky has been let go.

There is a delay because any given atom in the material only cares about its distances to its neighboring atoms, which determines the forces that atom feels. Most forces are based on distances.

Imagine a rope ABCD

Letting go of the rope at A will change the forces on just atoms of A. After those atoms move, the forces between A and B will change, so only then will B move. Only then will the forces between B and C change, so only then will C move. You can think of this as a domino effect. This is a basic explanation of how materials have a speed of sound, the speed at which this domino effect takes place.

None of the fundamental forces update faster than the speed of light in vacuum. So when an atom 1 light-second away wiggles, there are no forces that will let you know that it's wiggled, so there is no way to respond, for at least 1 second.